# Create awk script with 3 separated awk begin commands

Tags: awk

I have this three awk commands in seperated script, but i would need to have them **all** in the **same awk script** usign the following command.
How it's supposed to be merged to work correctly with a **while** ?

Command:

```
gawk -f sc.awk sh1.csv > sh2.csv
```

awk script:

```
   #Update id column 
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{print "new_id",$0;next} {print FNR-1,$0}
```

Second awk

```
    #Extraxt year from date 
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{$4="year,date"; print $0} NR!=1{sub(/[0-9]{4}/, "&,&", $4); print $0}
```

Third awk

```
#Delete surnames
        BEGIN{
          FS=","
          OFS=","
        }{
        while(sub(/ [[:alpha:]]+$/,"",$3))
        {}}
        {print}
```

Dataset:

```
id,name,date,manner_of_death,armed,age,gender,race,city,state,signs_of_mental_illness,threat_level,flee,body_camera,longitude,latitude,is_geocoding_exact
3,Tim Elliot,2015-01-02,shot,gun,53,M,A,Shelton,WA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-123.122,47.247,True
4,Lewis Lee Lembke,2015-01-02,shot,gun,47,M,W,Aloha,OR,False,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.892,45.487,True
8,Matthew Hoffman,2015-01-04,shot,toy weapon,32,M,W,San Francisco,CA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.422,37.763,True
```

Output expected:

```
new_id,id,name,year,date,manner_of_death,armed,age,gender,race,city,state,signs_of_mental_illness,threat_level,flee,body_camera,longitude,latitude,is_geocoding_exact
1,3,Tim,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,53,M,A,Shelton,WA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-123.122,47.247,True
2,4,Lewis,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,47,M,W,Aloha,OR,False,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.892,45.487,True
3,8,Matthew,2015,2015-01-04,shot,toy weapon,32,M,W,San Francisco,CA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.422,37.763,True
```

Comment: You have one `BEGIN` rule and then describe w;hat you will do in additional rules. You can write as many rules as you like in any awk script. Just write them in the order you need, and don't forget you can use `next` to skip any of the reaming rules and start processing the next record. You are pretty close in your thinking. Try putting it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can write all three scripts as a single awk script. As with any awk script, you simply take the changes you need to make one-at-a-time and you write a rule to accomplish this. In your case, you can rewrite `sc.awk` as follows:

```
BEGIN {                   # begin rule
  FS = OFS = ","
}

FNR == 1 {                # first line rule
  $3 = "year,date"
  print "new_id", $0
  next
}

{                         # all other records
  year = $3               # save $3 as year
  sub(/-.*$/,"",year)     # remove - to end leaving year
  sub(/ .*$/,"",$2)       # remove surname
  $3 = year "," $3        # update new $3 field
  print ++n, $0           # output new_id and record
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in `file` you would have:

```
$ awk -f sc.awk file
new_id,id,name,year,date,manner_of_death,armed,age,gender,race,city,state,signs_of_mental_illness,threat_level,flee,body_camera,longitude,latitude,is_geocoding_exact
1,3,Tim,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,53,M,A,Shelton,WA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-123.122,47.247,True
2,4,Lewis,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,47,M,W,Aloha,OR,False,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.892,45.487,True
3,8,Matthew,2015,2015-01-04,shot,toy weapon,32,M,W,San Francisco,CA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.422,37.763,True
```

Comment: how do you do this exact with a while?

Comment: What do you mean "with a while?" Awk automatically processes each record (line) in the file, one-by-one, applying each rule you have written in order to every record. Where do you see a `while` being needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the 3 separate `awk` scripts ***and*** you want to be able to run them 'together', one simple (though not very efficient) method:

```
awk -f sh1.awk sh1.csv |  awk -f sh2.awk | awk -f sh3.awk > sh2.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ cat sh2.csv
new_id,id,name,year,date,manner_of_death,armed,age,gender,race,city,state,signs_of_mental_illness,threat_level,flee,body_camera,longitude,latitude,is_geocoding_exact
1,3,Tim,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,53,M,A,Shelton,WA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-123.122,47.247,True
2,4,Lewis,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,47,M,W,Aloha,OR,False,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.892,45.487,True
3,8,Matthew,2015,2015-01-04,shot,toy weapon,32,M,W,San Francisco,CA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.422,37.763,True
```

---

On the other hand, if the intention is to merge the 3 separate scripts into one you can re-use your current code by figuring out the correct order and adjusting the field references based on the original input file, eg:

```
$ cat sh_all.awk
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { $3="year,date"; print "new_id",$0; next} 
       { while(sub(/ [[:alpha:]]+$/,"",$2)) {}
         sub(/[0-9]{4}/, "&,&", $3)
         print FNR-1,$0
       }
```

Taking for a spin:

```
awk -f sh_all.awk sh1.csv > sh2.csv
```

This also generates:

```
$ cat sh2.csv
new_id,id,name,year,date,manner_of_death,armed,age,gender,race,city,state,signs_of_mental_illness,threat_level,flee,body_camera,longitude,latitude,is_geocoding_exact
1,3,Tim,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,53,M,A,Shelton,WA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-123.122,47.247,True
2,4,Lewis,2015,2015-01-02,shot,gun,47,M,W,Aloha,OR,False,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.892,45.487,True
3,8,Matthew,2015,2015-01-04,shot,toy weapon,32,M,W,San Francisco,CA,True,attack,Not fleeing,False,-122.422,37.763,True
```